# How to attach Image and Audio file to E-mail in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to attach Image and audio file to E-Mail.How to do that.I found a lot here on SO but still cannot get the solution of it.I tried a lot.
Please someone Help me for my this issue.Thanks in Advance.My code is:

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {});
        // email.setType("image/png");
        email.setType("*/*");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, TAG);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                getResources().getText(R.string.Message));

        ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

        Uri imageUri1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                + "/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        // Uri imageUri2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +
        // getPackageName()
        // + "/" + R.drawable.twitter);

        Uri imageUri2 = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/Male_Hard_2.mp3");

        imageUris.add(imageUri1); // Add your image URIs here
        imageUris.add(imageUri2);

        email.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);

        // AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        // InputStream inputStream = null;
        // try {
        // inputStream = assetManager.open("Male_Hard_2.mp3");
        // } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log.e("message: ", e.getMessage());
        // }

        // Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +
        // "/"
        // + R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        //
        // Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/male_hard_2");
        //
        // email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        //
        // email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri1);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email,
                "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Comment: you can only send file that are on Sdcard(Not APK resource) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946203/android-mime-type-for-email-attachment-not-set/13584068#13584068

Comment: Actually I got the Image but i don't know how to attach audio file from my assets folder to Email.

Comment: No, you are wrong. Just be sure are you really able to send images from resources? check reciever side. I'm sure you need to put files in Sdcard and then you can.

Comment: yes i got the image in Receiver side by applying setType("image/png").There is no issue of that.but i dont know how to attach audio file from the assets folder.

Comment: are you able to open the image on receiver-side?

Comment: yes i am receiving on Recieverside

Answer (score 1):

try this one for audio file:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("audio/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"someone@gmail.com"} );
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MySubject");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "audiorecorder.3gpp");
    startActivity(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code...

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"email"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Test");
//has to be an ArrayList
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
//convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
for (String file : filePaths)
{
    File fileIn = new File(file);
    Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
    uris.add(u);
}
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
context.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: i want to attach audio file from assets folder to E-Mail.I dont want to take it from SD Card.

Comment: so put your file path at filePaths in for loop

Answer (score 0):

I have attached the sample code with attachement image from sdcard in MailSenderActivity(m.attachment()) ..try this

**MailSenderActivity.java**

public class MailSenderActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final String GMAIL_EMAIL_ID = "";
private static final String GMAIL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = "";
private static final String TO_ADDRESSES = "";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

MailSender.execute();

```
}

class MailSender extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MailSenderActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Sending...");
        pd.setMessage("Mail Sending. Please wait...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

    }


    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {


        Mail m = new Mail(GMAIL_EMAIL_ID, GMAIL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);

        String toAddresses = TO_ADDRESSES;
        m.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        m.setFromAddress(GMAIL_EMAIL_ID);
        m.setMailSubject("captured image.");
        m.setMailBody("Email body.");

        try {

             m.addAttachment("/mnt/sdcard/cpimg.jpg");

            if (m.send()) {
                System.out.println("Message sent");
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 2;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        }
        return 3;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();

        if (result == 1)
            Toast.makeText(MailSenderActivity.this,
                    "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        else if (result == 2)
            Toast.makeText(MailSenderActivity.this, "Email was not sent.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else if (result == 3)
            Toast.makeText(MailSenderActivity.this,
                    "There was a problem sending the email.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

Hope this will help..

Comment: do you know how to attache audio file to email from assets folder using Intent?